# React native, how to show specific data from database to update

Tags: php, react-native

I am using react native to do register form that can sign up, login, update and delete. I have problem with when I want to update student information but it come out all student detail to me. For example, I login as student A, I want to only student A detail and then click it, It will send detail to update interface to give user update. But now the problem is, I login as Student A, I can see other student name for me to choose to update their detail. How to do if I only one to show the detail for who are login only?

Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: First a fall you need to store user data somewhere whomsoever is being logged in like in local storage of browser or etc. For secure data auth you can use JWT which help to generate token. JWT: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347645/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After your update I advise you to read more about authentication by tokens. In comments to your question you can find mention of JWT token, also you can read about OAuth algorithm or smth else. As far as you use your server only as an API it's the best solution to use tokens for requests authentication. But now for fastest development I advise you to return user id after authorization.

Change authorization code part with response to this:

```
if (isset($check)) {
    echo json_encode($check); 
}
```

Now you will get all user data after authorization as JSON string. Save user ID and pass it to the next request as GET param or header so you'll be able to determine on the server side which user executes this request. You can get user ID from GET param from global `$_GET` variable like this:

```
$loggedInUserId = $_GET['userId'];
```

Or from the header:

```
$loggedInUserId = $_SERVER['LOGGED_IN_USER_ID'];
```

And then you can use this variable inside your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  userregisterinfo WHERE id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($loggedInUserId);
```

So you can get only one row from the table with data of particular user

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the  .$loggedInUserId need to declare? If need how ?

Comment: You have to store an id of logged in user into session for example or pass it somehow to script. I need to see how you authorize a user to make my answer more correct. Pls provide more information about authorization.

Comment: Nope, only 3 lines with `if`, other code is for the first part of PHP code

Comment: ok, I get the error with  "Value for title cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to String"    what should I change inside here     .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if (responseJson === 'Data Matched') {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Second');
                }
                else {
                    Alert.alert(responseJson);
                }

Comment: Because now you get from server not the string "Data Matched", you get full data about user which are casted to ReadableNativeMap

Comment: so I delete the part? I need to replace what or not?

Comment: You have to change your JS code according to data which now you can get from the server

Comment: I am sorry that this is my first time using react-native, I don't know how to change actually. I delete the data matched then I change my code like this:      .then((responseJson) => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Second');
                    Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
               
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });     then the result is the output at popup message about the student detail but behind the pop up have error "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized '<'

Comment: @iceblue look at the data which you get from the server, perhaps some error occurred

Comment: Based on your step, it work about show detail who login, but the result is popup message it will not pass the data to second activity. In my original coding is can send to second page but show all student detail, now is show one person detail in popup message but can't pass data to another page to update. I update again my code at question

Comment: @iceblue I'm not familiar with react native so I can't help you with it, sorry. You can look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662857/react-native-passing-data-from-one-screen-to-another